# Relative path not working when website is deployed

Tags: asp.net-2.0, windows-server-2003

I have a website that has a relative path to a stylesheet that looks like this "/stylesheets/main.css".  Now this works fine when I run the site in Visual Studio.  But when I deploy the site to our Windows Server 2003 the path stops working. If I go back into code and change the path from "/stylesheets/main.css" to "stylesheets/main.css", the site works fine on the server.  I have another website on a different server that uses the same path style ("/stylesheets/main.css") and stylesheet and works with no problems.  I really don't want to change all the paths, and am not even sure if this is a problem with the code or the server.  Any help or ideas would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is the site deployed to the domain's root?  If the site is at

```
http://example.com/somefolder/
```

then the path `/stylesheet/main.css` will be interpreted as

```
http://example.com/stylesheet/main.css
```

rather than

```
http://example.com/somefolder/stylesheet/main.css
```

As @Kit indicated, you can work around this by resolving the path to your application's folder.  I have often done this in ASP.NET as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/xss" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/stylesheet/main.css") %>"/>
```

If that's not the problem, you're going to have to give a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks this did help a lot. But I had to use a combination of different ways on the same site to get it to work. "/default.aspx" to "<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") %>" "/default.aspx" to "~/default.aspx" url('/images/top.gif') to url('../images/top.gif') And even for one case had to keep the old path type ("/stylesheets/main.css"). This seems very weird to me and I've never had this problem before but I guess it seems like this did the trick.

Comment: How to work around this when path specified in css file so I cannot put Resolve() method call?

Comment: @sll, CSS already resolves relative paths relative to the stylesheet, so no path munging should be necessary.

Comment: Hi Harpo - I have a similar query here - I have a site were all paths were previously relative but I need to now include the virtual directory name - is this possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513113/select-correct-path-for-files-from-app-under-iis

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET, many times you will need to use a tilde (`~`) to get the ***application***'s root directory, so your paths would look like `~/stylesheets/main.css`

When you specify a path that starts with `/` you are indicating the *server* root so if you have you site in a virtual directory, it will not be taken into account, but if the site is hosted as the default site, the path will qualify:

Example: server named `foo.net` with site hosted in a virtual directory named `app`
`/stylesheet` will translate to `foo.net/stylesheet` *not* `foo.net/app/stylesheet`

Comment: Hi Kit - I have a similar query here - I have a site were all paths were previously relative but I need to now include the virtual directory name - is this possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513113/select-correct-path-for-files-from-app-under-iis

Comment: @TheRiddler I took a closer look at the question you linked, and I'll have to agree with the top answer (at this time). Updating all the relative links to be application-directory aware (using `~`) should be worth you time. I thought that if you have the application and the site as the same thing, the leading `~` will effectively function the same as `/` just not the other way around, does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks Kit I think I may just host it at same level as my default website on iis and the relative paths will work

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to not use relative path and instead use the full path relative to the server.  You can do this by processing the  tag of your document at the server.  So, something like this:

```
<head runat="server">
  <link href="~/stylesheet/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

The tilde (~) signifies that you are coming from the root directory of the website.  The reason this works is because you are processing the head at the server.  Note that this will work for any other tag that is processed at the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

A URL path of the form

```
/path_preceded_by_a_slash
```

is *not* a relative path... it's an absolute path, indicating that the path search should start at the `DocumentRoot` and not the directory that contains the requesting document.

Perhaps that's your problem. You should be using relative paths, but you are not  doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When using an absolute path (eg. /images/cool_image.gif') , the root folder is the application root folder set by IIS.

Just as a tricky aside, if you are using a Visual Studio ASP .NET Web *Application* project, the root of your application is set when you set up the Web Application in your IIS or Web Hosting control panel.

If you're using a Visual Studio ASP .NET Web *Site* project, then the application is compiled automatically 'on the fly' and the root is probably the general IIS root folder, since no application needs to be explicitly set up in IIS.  This is unlikely to coincide with the actual root of your application, and for that reason these kind of absolute paths should be avoided in 'Web Site' projects.

For a discussion of Visual Studio 'Web Site' versus 'Web Application', google it - it's a hot topic.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for future readers, i would like to add that, i noticed that sometimes to make virtual paths to work is mandatory to remove the runat="server" part from the head and when dragging any file in to the page that belongs to the main folder you need to remove the "~" or "..." from the path.
something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
 <script src="javascript/Red/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

that works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js") %>"></script>
```