# .NET 8 Blazor server static files routing

Tags: c#, .net, iis, blazor

I recently migrated our .net 6 blazor server app to .net 8.
Everything works fine except that the app can't find the static css/js files when deploying.
The app is setup as a subsite in IIS to another main site, for example:
"https:\mainsite.com\virtual-path-to-subsite".

Instead of looking for the css/js files in:
"https:\mainsite.com\virtual-path-to-subsite\site.css".
the path specified is:
"https:\mainsite.com\site.css".

Any ideas?

I tried changing "UseStaticFiles" to route to the subsite but then the pipeline fails because there isn't a physical folder in that path.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related with tthe relative path, could you pls take a look at this answer and have a try? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2411175

Comment: Seems to be related. 
In previous versions of Blazor the base path was specified as:
<base href="~/" />
in .NET 8 as:
<base href="/" />